Keeping a constant identifying value at the beginning of a recursively unioning cte
As part of a T-SQL project on a Microsoft SQL Server, I'm using a recursively unioning CTE to trace a series of child parent relationships through some hierarchical data to pull each individual element into a row that I can then pivot into a single row.
As an example, my recursively unioning CTE would turn the following rows from A (the source table) to B (the recursively unioned table) for four of the HCC values. C would be the desired outcome after the pivot.
A



MEMBER_NAME
PARENT_NAME




HCC_AS1
SEC_SMI


SEC_SMI
BRC_AND


BRC_AND
OBU_AND


HCC_AK4
BRC_BOZ


BRC_BOZ
OBU_LKY


HCC_BH1
OBU_BGH


HCC_Z5
SEC_LNG


SEC_LNG
BRC_LYN


BRC_LYN
OBU_LNM



B



MEMBER_NAME
PARENT_NAME
Hierarchy
Value




HCC_AS1
SEC_SMI
SEC
SMI


HCC_AS1
SEC_SMI
BRC
AND


HCC_AS1
SEC_SMI
OBU
AND


HCC_AK4
BRC_BOZ
BRC
BOZ


HCC_AK4
BRC_BOZ
OBU
LKY


HCC_BH1
OBU_BGH
OBU
BGH


HCC_Z5
SEC_LNG
SEC
LNG


HCC_Z5
SEC_LNG
BRC
LYN


HCC_Z5
SEC_LNG
OBU
LNM



C



MEMBER_NAME
PARENT_NAME
SEC
BRC
OBU




HCC_AS1
SEC_SMI
SMI
AND
AND


HCC_AK4
BRC_BOZ

BOZ
LKY


HCC_BH1
OBU_BGH


BGH


HCC_Z5
SEC_LNG
LNG
LYN
LNM



The only thing I'm having trouble with is preserving the original MEMBER_NAME and PARENT_NAME for the whole recursive CTE which is a requirement of the project. I wrapped it in a cursor and inserted into a temp table so I had something for them to look at but they want to change it to a view so I don't believe my current design will hold up. I'm not terribly proficient with recursive queries. Is there a solution that I'm missing that could be used to make this into a view?
DECLARE @member varchar(80)
DECLARE @parent varchar(80)

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    MEMBER_NAME varchar(80),
    PARENT_NAME varchar(80),
    Hierarchy varchar(80),
    [Value] varchar(80)
);
 
DECLARE member_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT
        [MEMBER_NAME], [PARENT_NAME]
    FROM 
        [CACHED_OUTLINE_MEMBERS]
    WHERE 
        DIMENSION_NAME = 'Delivery_Center'
        AND LEFT(MEMBER_NAME, 3) = 'HCC'
        AND LEFT(PARENT_NAME, 3) IN ('SEC', 'OBU', 'BRC')
 
OPEN member_cursor
 
FETCH NEXT FROM member_cursor INTO @member, @parent
 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    WITH Parent AS
    (
        SELECT
            LEFT(PARENT_NAME, CHARINDEX('_', Parent_name) -1) AS Hierarchy,
            RIGHT(Parent_name, LEN(parent_name) - CHARINDEX('_', Parent_name)) AS [Value]
        FROM 
            [CACHED_OUTLINE_MEMBERS]
        WHERE
            MEMBER_NAME = @member
 
        UNION ALL
 
        SELECT
            LEFT(C.PARENT_NAME, CHARINDEX('_', C.Parent_name) -1) AS Hierarchy, 
            RIGHT(C.Parent_name, LEN(C.parent_name) - CHARINDEX('_', C.Parent_name)) AS [Value]
        FROM 
            [CACHED_OUTLINE_MEMBERS] C
        INNER JOIN 
            Parent ON C.member_name = parent.parent_name
        WHERE
            LEFT(C.PARENT_NAME, CHARINDEX('_', C.Parent_name) -1) IN ('SEC', 'OBU', 'BRC')
    )
    INSERT INTO #Temp
        SELECT 
            @member AS MEMBER_NAME, @parent AS PARENT_NAME, Hierarchy, [Value]  
        FROM
            Parent
 
    FETCH NEXT FROM member_cursor INTO @member, @parent 
END
 
CLOSE member_cursor
DEALLOCATE member_cursor
 
SELECT * FROM #Temp

I tried the cursor but that was when I thought this could just be a table that was built once a day. They want it to be a view though so I'd have to come up with a design that doesn't take a cursor.
Before I landed on a recursive CTE, I tried just doing a self joining table but the child parent relationship for the data is not consistent. Some HCC values don't have a SEC or BRC or both so just doing three self joins would sometimes land OBUs in the SEC or BRC columns.

I think you need to add a bit more test data and expected rows so one can understand what you're trying to display and what kind of data relations can exist

Sure, if you think it will help. I've added the info for 3 more HCCs that follow the 3 different relationship paths that can be found in the source table.
My Original Example HCC_AS1 ran the full spectrum. Its relations go HCC ->SEC->BRC->OBU. The new example  HCC_Z5 has the same relations.
HCC_AK4 doesn't have a SEC relation. It goes HCC -> BRC -> OBU
HCC_BH1 doesn't have a SEC or BRC relation. It goes HCC -> OBU

Something like this perhaps:
WITH data AS (
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'HCC_AS1', N'SEC_SMI')
    ,   (N'SEC_SMI', N'BRC_AND')
    ,   (N'BRC_AND', N'OBU_AND')
    ,   (N'HCC_AK4', N'BRC_BOZ')
    ,   (N'BRC_BOZ', N'OBU_LKY')
    ,   (N'HCC_BH1', N'OBU_BGH')
    ,   (N'HCC_Z5', N'SEC_LNG')
    ,   (N'SEC_LNG', N'BRC_LYN')
    ,   (N'BRC_LYN', N'OBU_LNM')
) t (MEMBER_NAME,PARENT_NAME)
)
, cte AS (
    SELECT  MEMBER_NAME AS anchor, PARENT_NAME AS parent_anchor, PARENT_NAME AS parent, LEFT(PARENT_NAME, 3) AS hierarchy, RIGHT(PARENT_NAME, 3) AS Value
    FROM    data d
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT  1
            FROM    data d2
            WHERE   d2.parent_name = d.member_name
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  anchor, parent_anchor, d.parent_name, LEFT(PARENT_NAME, 3) AS hierarchy, RIGHT(PARENT_NAME, 3) AS Value
    FROM    cte c
    INNER JOIN data d
        ON  d.MEMBER_NAME = c.parent
)
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  anchor, parent_anchor, hierarchy, value
    FROM    cte
    ) x
PIVOT (max(value) FOR hierarchy IN (SEC, BRC,OBU)) y


I create two columns which are kept as anchors and don't change from the top
Then one can do the standard recursive CTE thing for the rest of the columns.
Finally, for the pivot, i remove the unnecessary parent column and create the pivot from the rest of the fields.

Output:



anchor
parent_anchor
SEC
BRC
OBU




HCC_AK4
BRC_BOZ
NULL
BOZ
LKY


HCC_BH1
OBU_BGH
NULL
NULL
BGH


HCC_Z5
SEC_LNG
LNG
LYN
LNM


HCC_AS1
SEC_SMI
SMI
AND
AND




That did it. I knew it would be obvious once I saw it and it was. Thank you very much.
